# Flurry Analytics from Corona SDK - How do you log event parameters?

Tags: coronasdk, flurry

Code below create event logs instead of event parameters with Flurry.

```
eventParams = {}
eventParams["key"] = value
analytics.logEvent(EVENT_NAME, eventParams)
```

How do you log event parameters in Flurry from Corona SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Since Flurry doesn't officially support Corona SDK, please reach out to support@flurry.com indicating your complete platform details and API key of the App and Flurry SDK version being used. We will get back to you.

I work in the support team at Flurry.

Thanks